# form values not submitted to the servlet

Tags: java, jsp, jakarta-ee, servlets

I am trying to submit the text field value and print it using the servlet. The index.jsp is my main page and I am using jsp:include to include the form which reside in another page which is login.html.

here is the code i have for login.html

```
<form id="f1" action="ControllerServlet" method="GET">
<p>username
<input class ="text-input" type="text" id="txtusername" />
</p>
<p>
<input type="submit" value="submit" />
</p>
```

the index.jsp

```
<div id="col3_content" class="clearfix">

        <h1>H1 Heading</h1>
        <jsp:include page="login.html"></jsp:include>
      </div>
```

the controller servlet

```
String usrname = request.getParameter("txtusername").toString();

        out.print(usrname);
```

The problem is this is throwing a null pointer exception. what am I doing wrong here ? any help appreciated. thanks

Comment: Which method is overriden?  doPost or doGet

Comment: You don't need to invoke toString() on request.getParameter(), it is already a String.

Answer (score 5):

Please use **name** not **id**

```
<input class ="text-input" type="text" name="txtusername" />
```

Comment: Do not omit `id` attribute as OP might be using it somewhere like in javascript for validation.

Answer (score 1):

The `id` is not used to identify the name of the input parameter. The right attribute for the parameter is `name`, currently you are using an `input` without a name. So use

```
<input class ="text-input" type="text" name="txtusername" id="txtusername" />
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to define `name` attribute of input tag to get it in Servlet by name.

```
<input class ="text-input" type="text" id="txtusername" name="txtusername" />
```

Also make sure you are writing code in doGet or service method of servlet as you have GET as action in form tag.

Answer (score 0):

```
Code for Login.html

<form action="ControllerServlet" method="GET"> 
<p>username :
<input type ="text" name="txtusername" /></p> 
<p><input type="submit" value="submit" /> </p> 
</form>

ControllerServlet.java

public void service(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response)
{
String username = request.getParameter("txtusername");
PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
out.println("User Name " + username)
```

Answer (score 0):

I faced a similar situation, when I checked front end, the form seems to have all the value populated correctly. However, after form.submit, from server side using request.getParameter("the parameter") does not return the value populated. After tuning on the network traffic tab in browser, I see the parameter was there, but there was a typo.
Hopefully could save you some time if same thing happens to you.